# colorprint - An ANSI Escape sequence console writer mini-library

Tags: c, console, formatting, c99

I wrote this a long time ago. I came back to it and decided to clean it up a little.

It uses the preprocessor and C99 `anon structs` to make a flexible python-like API for calling its functions.

#### colorprint.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "colorprint.h"

static const char *numch = "0123456789";

static void
apply_effect(char *out, enum fx fx)
{/*{{{*/
    char buf[3] = { numch[fx - 1], ';' };

    strcat(out, buf);
}/*}}}*/

static void
apply_fg(char *out, enum color c)
{/*{{{*/
    char buf[4] = { '3', numch[c - 1], 'm' };

    strcat(out, buf);
}/*}}}*/

static void
apply_bg(char *out, enum color c)
{/*{{{*/
    char buf[4] = { '4', numch[c - 1], ';' };

    strcat(out, buf);
}/*}}}*/

static void
apply_fx(char *out, enum fx *fx)
{/*{{{*/
    for(int i = 0; fx[i]; i++)
        apply_effect(out, fx[i]);
}/*}}}*/

static void
apply_colors(char *out, struct cpoptions *cpo)
{/*{{{*/
    if(cpo->bg)
        apply_bg(out, cpo->bg);

    if(cpo->fg)
        apply_fg(out, cpo->fg);
}/*}}}*/

void
_cprint(struct cpoptions *cpo)
{/*{{{*/
    char options[30] = "";

    apply_fx(options, cpo->fx);
    apply_colors(options, cpo);

    if(!cpo->fg && !cpo->bg && !cpo->fx[0])
         fputs(cpo->string, stdout);
    else
        printf("\e[%s%s\e[0m", options, cpo->string);
}/*}}}*/

void
_cputs(struct cpoptions *cpo)
{/*{{{*/
    _cprint(cpo);
    putchar('\n');
}/*}}}*/
```

#### colorprint.h

```
#define func(name, type, ...) \
    name(&(type){.header = 0, __VA_ARGS__})

enum color {
    color_invalid,
    color_black,
    color_red, 
    color_green,
    color_yellow,
    color_blue,
    color_purple,
    color_aqua, 
    color_white
};

enum fx {
    fx_invalid,
    fx_plain,
    fx_bold,
    fx_dark,
    fx_italic,
    fx_underline,
    fx_light,
    fx_light2,
    fx_reverse,
    fx_blink,
    fx_strike
};

struct cpoptions {
    char header;
    char *string;
    enum fx fx[10];
    enum color fg;
    enum color bg;
};

void _cprint(struct cpoptions *cpo);
void _cputs(struct cpoptions *cpo);

#define cprint(...) func(_cprint, struct cpoptions, __VA_ARGS__)
#define cputs(...) func(_cputs, struct cpoptions, __VA_ARGS__)

/* Example: 
 *      cprint("Hello World", .fg = color_green, .fx = {fx_bold, fx_italic, fx_strike});
 * Or: 
 *      struct cpoptions cpo = {
 *          .string = "Hello World",
 *          .fg = color_green,
 *          .fx = {
 *              fx_bold,
 *              fx_italic,
 *              fx_strike
 *          }
 *      };
 *      _cprint(&cpo);
 */
```

Its usage ranges in complexity from

```
cputs("Hello World"); // prints "Hello World\n"
```

to

```
cputs( .string = "Hello World",
       .fg = color_green,
       .bg = color_red,
       .fx = {
           fx_bold,
           fx_strike,
           fx_italic
        }
); // prints "\e[1;9;3;41;32mHello World\e[0m\n", which appears as "Hello World" with a red background, green foreground, with bold+strikethrough+italic effects
```

In my opinion, this method of function calling is far more type-safe and versatile than the horrid `va_args`. It's also nice because it allows colorful output without the overhead of `ncurses` or `termcap`.

Comment: Here is a screencast, for those interested: https://youtu.be/qdBiKTqlzGw

Comment: Followup: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142167/colorprint-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Architecture: IMO, the time for trusting that `char *` buffers will not overflow is past.  Pass in a `size_t size` and check for valid sizes in function calls.
2. `static const char *numch = "0123456789";` serves little value and its application can cause UB on unruly input.  Rather than use it convert to digit character, just add `'0'`, offset as needed.  `numch[fx - 1]` --> `fx - 1 + '0'`
3. Global functions that being with `_` are reserve for the implementation. Use a different name.

   ```
   // void _cprint(struct cpoptions *cpo)
   void cp_print(struct cpoptions *cpo)
   ```
4. `\e` is a non-standard escape sequence.  Use `\033` or ...

   ```
   // printf("\e[%s%s\e[0m"
   #define ESC 27
   printf("%c[%s%s\e[0m", ESC
   ```
5. `colorprint.h` should have a protective `#ifndef`  to cope with re-entrantcy.

   ```
   #ifndef colorprint_h
   #define colorprint_h
      ... // existing content
   #endif
   ```
6. I found useful enumerating the `Nth` item

   ```
   enum color {
       color_invalid,
       color_white,
       color_N  // add
   };

   if (value >= color_N) Handle_InvalidValue(value);
   ```
7. Nice to have example usage in .h file.  Suggest `#if 0` bracketing instead as it does not stop syntax highlighting.
8. Pedantic: `size_t` is the type to use for array indexing rather than `int`.  Code accordingly, remember that `size_t` is some unsigned type.
9. Namespace `colorprint.h` abuses namespace with `color_...`, `fx_...`, `cp...`.  Suggest a more uniform prefix.  `cp...` is not too bad, but then use `cp.h`.
10. Avoid magic number - why 30?  Numbers other than -1,0,1,2 and maybe [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker's_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) deserve a macro or `const` object.

    ```
    char options[30] = "";
    ```
11. Do not include files *before* `"colorprint.h"`. `"colorprint.c"` should do this to insure `"colorprint.h"` is not dependant on some `<*.h>` file
12. tidy up, remove `/*{{{*/`, etc.
13. Good use of `static` functions.
14. Print-like functions should return `int`.

    ```
    /// void _cprint(
    int  _cprint(
      ...
      int i = printf("\e[%s%s\e[0m", options, cpo->string);
      return i;
    }
    ```
15. `func` is much too common to use as a macro name

    ```
    // #define func(name, type, ...) \
    #define cp_func(name, type, ...) \
    ```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on 1 and 7? As for #10, I specifically calculated the maximum possible size of a string generated by the `apply_*` functions, and it came out to `27` bytes. 30 is just more round. Are you suggesting that I instead use a macro like `#define CP_BUFSZ ((10 * 2) + (2 * 3) + 1)`?

Comment: @Braden #10: Yes, `#define CP_BUFSZ ...` is a good idea. `10` should not be hard coded either, but some macro/constant like `fx_N` see #6 #1: cancel with #10 change.    #7: Rather than `/* Example:... */`, use `#if 0 ... #endif`.   #16: Minor: Recommend testing `if (cpo->string)`  before using it.  #17: `header` field usage unclear - in general a bit more documentation in `*.h` would be useful.

Comment: @Braden As the user sets up the fields of `struct cpoptions` suggest validating them as able, before using them in the `.c` file

Comment: The intent of `header` was to make it so that the struct doesn't get populated as `{}` when a function is called with no arguments (`fn()`). Though I've since decided to remove `header` and let the compiler validate the usage of the function *for* me, since there's supposed to at least be one argument anyway.

Comment: Anyways, I've made edits purporting to `1-7`, `9-12`, and `14-17`. I went ahead and pushed the current version to a [gitlab repo](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/colorprint/tree/master)

Comment: @Braden Best   Further on edge case, `for(int i = 0; fx[i]; i++)` relies on user entering < 10 elements in `.fx = { fx_bold, fx_italic,  fx_strike }`.  Although that is _reasonable_ , better to limit loop iteration count to something like `fx_N`, exiting early on `fx[i]==0`.

Comment: Yes, have you seen the [repo with the updated code](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/colorprint/tree/master)? I've already taken care of that edge case. `for(int i = 0; fx[i] && i < CP_FX_END - 1; i++)`where `CP_FX_END` is the final value in the `fx` enum type, equal to 11.

Comment: @Braden Have not seen (maybe I need to be a member to see all).  I think you want `i < CP_FX_END - 1 && fx[i]` to prevent access to non-existant `fx[10]` or use the classic idiom `i < sizeof fx/sizeof fx[0] && fx[i]`.

Comment: Good idea. I can view the repo while logged out. Try the raw versions? [colorprint.c](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/colorprint/raw/master/colorprint.c), [colorprint.h](https://gitlab.com/bradenbest/colorprint/raw/master/colorprint.h)

Comment: Should you want a re-review, this site has guidelines on how to  post again.  Good luck with your nifty code.

Comment: Okay. If you're interested, I just posted [such a question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142167/colorprint-part-2)