# colorprint - part 2

Tags: c, console, formatting, c99

This is a followup of the [last review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141985/colorprint-an-ansi-escape-sequence-console-writer-mini-library) to comply with [meta's rules](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c).

In the last, I posted a small library called `colorprint` and got some helpful pointers from chux in [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142079/91054).

---

### colorprint.c

```
#include "colorprint.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CP_BUFSZ ((3 * 2) + (2 * (CP_FX_END - 1)) + 1)

enum validate_error {
    VE_OK,
    VE_FXTOOLARGE,
    VE_TOOMANYFX,
    VE_FGTOOLARGE,
    VE_BGTOOLARGE,
    VE_BADSTRING,
    VE_END
};

const char *validate_error_str[VE_END] = {
    [VE_FXTOOLARGE] = "(.fx) one or more effect values are out of bounds",
    [VE_TOOMANYFX]  = "(.fx) too many effects (the \"trap\" effect was set)",
    [VE_FGTOOLARGE] = "(.fg) foreground color out of bounds",
    [VE_BGTOOLARGE] = "(.bg) background color out of bounds",
    [VE_BADSTRING]  = "(.string) no string provided"
};

static void
apply_effect(char *out, enum fx fx)
{
    char buf[3] = { '0' + (fx - 1), ';' };

    strcat(out, buf);
}

static void
apply_fg(char *out, enum color c)
{
    char buf[4] = { '3', '0' + (c - 1), 'm' };

    strcat(out, buf);
}

static void
apply_bg(char *out, enum color c)
{
    char buf[4] = { '4', '0' + (c - 1), ';' };

    strcat(out, buf);
}

static void
apply_fx(char *out, enum fx *fx)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < CP_FX_END - 1 && fx[i]; i++)
        apply_effect(out, fx[i]);
}

static void
apply_colors(char *out, struct cpoptions *cpo)
{
    if(cpo->bg)
        apply_bg(out, cpo->bg);

    if(cpo->fg)
        apply_fg(out, cpo->fg);
}

static enum validate_error
validate_cpo(struct cpoptions *cpo)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < CP_FX_END - 1 && cpo->fx[i]; i++)
        if(cpo->fx[i] >= CP_FX_END)
            return VE_FXTOOLARGE;

    if(cpo->fx[CP_FX_END - 1] != CP_FX_INVALID)
        return VE_TOOMANYFX;

    if(cpo->fg >= CP_COLOR_END)
        return VE_FGTOOLARGE;

    if(cpo->bg >= CP_COLOR_END)
        return VE_BGTOOLARGE;

    if(cpo->string == NULL)
        return VE_BADSTRING;

    return VE_OK;
}

int
cprint_default(struct cpoptions *cpo)
{
    char options[CP_BUFSZ] = "";
    enum validate_error ve;

    if((ve = validate_cpo(cpo)) != VE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "colorprint: An error occurred. Details: E%03u (%s)\n", ve, validate_error_str[ve]);
        return -1;
    }

    apply_fx(options, cpo->fx);
    apply_colors(options, cpo);

    if(!cpo->fg && !cpo->bg && !cpo->fx[0])
        return fputs(cpo->string, stdout);
    else
        return printf("\033[%s%s\033[0m", options, cpo->string);
}

int
cputs_default(struct cpoptions *cpo)
{
    int ret = cprint_default(cpo);

    putchar('\n');
    return ret;
}
```

### colorprint.h

```
#ifndef COLORPRINT_H
#define COLORPRINT_H

#define CPFUNC(name, type, ...) \
    name(&(type){__VA_ARGS__})

enum color {
    CP_COLOR_INVALID,
    CP_COLOR_BLACK,
    CP_COLOR_RED, 
    CP_COLOR_GREEN,
    CP_COLOR_YELLOW,
    CP_COLOR_BLUE,
    CP_COLOR_PURPLE,
    CP_COLOR_AQUA, 
    CP_COLOR_WHITE,
    CP_COLOR_END
};

enum fx {
    CP_FX_INVALID,
    CP_FX_PLAIN,
    CP_FX_BOLD,
    CP_FX_DARK,
    CP_FX_ITALIC,
    CP_FX_UNDERLINE,
    CP_FX_LIGHT,
    CP_FX_LIGHT2,
    CP_FX_REVERSE,
    CP_FX_BLINK,
    CP_FX_STRIKE,
    CP_FX_END
};

struct cpoptions {
    char *string;
    enum fx fx[CP_FX_END];
    enum color fg;
    enum color bg;
};

int cprint_default(struct cpoptions *cpo);
int cputs_default(struct cpoptions *cpo);

#define cprint(...) CPFUNC(cprint_default, struct cpoptions, __VA_ARGS__)
#define cputs(...) CPFUNC(cputs_default, struct cpoptions, __VA_ARGS__)

#if 0

Example: 

    cprint("Hello World", .fg = CP_COLOR_GREEN, .fx = {CP_FX_BOLD, CP_FX_ITALIC, CP_FX_STRIKE});

Or... 

    struct cpoptions cpo = {
        .string = "Hello World",
        .fg = CP_COLOR_GREEN,
        .fx = {
            CP_FX_BOLD,
            CP_FX_ITALIC,
            CP_FX_STRIKE
        }
    };

    cprint_default(&cpo);

#endif

#endif
```

I will say that I am not a fan of the `#if 0` style comment suggested by [chux in his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/142079/91054). I personally find this much easier to read:

```
/*
 *
 *  Example: 
 *
 *      cprint("Hello World", .fg = CP_COLOR_GREEN, .fx = {CP_FX_BOLD, CP_FX_ITALIC, CP_FX_STRIKE});
 *
 *  Or... 
 *
 *      struct cpoptions cpo = {
 *          .string = "Hello World",
 *          .fg = CP_COLOR_GREEN,
 *          .fx = {
 *              CP_FX_BOLD,
 *              CP_FX_ITALIC,
 *              CP_FX_STRIKE
 *          }
 *      };
 *
 *      cprint_default(&cpo);
 *
 */
```

Because the `*` on the left side creates a margin that makes it easy to scan vertically and see where the comment begins and ends.

So I will probably change it back at some point.

Comment: To be clearer, suggest using `#if 0` for the code portion of the example.  Not a big issue either way.

Answer (score 3):

I've found some problems, and have already fixed them. So I will post them here in the style of an answer rather than break the rules and edit the question.

### 1. fx enum values are not completely accurate

The values `5` and `6` (`LIGHT, LIGHT2`) actually produce a blink effect, and `8` (`BLINK`) produces an "invisible" effect So...

```
// CP_FX_LIGHT,
// CP_FX_LIGHT2,
CP_FX_BLINK,
CP_FX_BLINK2,
...
// CP_FX_BLINK,
CP_FX_HIDDEN
```

### 2. Bug: Applying only a background color breaks the escape sequence

```
cputs("Hello World", .bg = CP_COLOR_BLUE);
// "?[44;Hello World?[0m"
```

It would be prudent to check for this:

```
if(cpo->fg)
    apply_fg(out, cpo->fg);
else
    // terminate the escape sequence
```